# Reading from clientsocket: ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled

Tags: c#, sockets, exception, tcpclient

I was using this tutorial to see how it works:
http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-chat-server-programming.htm

(http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-chat-client.htm)

This is what I've done:

- Downloaded the code
- Started two Visual Studio Instances : One for the Client Side, One for the Server Side.
- Ran the Server : Server running fine
- Ran Client Side, entered name in textbox, pressed connect button and this is what i get on this line in the Server Program :

  ```
  networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
  ```

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled.

I did not change the original code. Funny is that the same code I've downloaded two years ago and it worked fine (was on Windows 7, now I'm on Windows 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bytesFrom` is 10025 bytes long. The `clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize` in theory may become longer than this size (probably due to [Window Auto-Tuning feature](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/window-auto-tuning-in-windows-10)). To fix the issue initialize your buffer with `clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize`:

```
byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
```

Note also that in the client code you've got a similar issue in `getMessage()`. There you should also change buffer initialization code:

```
buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
byte[] inStream = new byte[buffSize];
serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Works fine now !